# How can I use my own parent.pom instead of the "spring-boot-starter-parent"?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am new to Spring, Spring boot, and Spring boot starter.

For my different apps I use an own `parent.pom` for what the have in common. The `parent.pom` contains the version numbers as properties and dependencies that use the properties as version numbers.

When using my parent.pom maven states that I have to use the `"spring-boot-starter-parent"`.

How can I use my own parent.pom instead of the "`spring-boot-starter-parent`"?

Meanwhile I changed the pom to this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.websystique.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootRestApiExample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>SpringBootRestApiExample</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>my</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>   
        <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
        <!-- Adds Tomcat and Spring MVC, along others -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But now I get this warning:

```
dependencies.dependency.scope' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'import'. @ line 27, column 1
```

Comment: Paste us your pom file. It will be easier to help you with it.

Comment: I recommend to read the docs about it: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent

Comment: an import works only in <dependencyManagement> and not in the <dependencies> area itself. Take a closer look to my answer please.

Answer (score 6):

You don't *have to* use `spring-boot-starter-parent`, it's just that it has an extensive `dependencyManagement` section that ensures all the Spring Boot dependencies you use in child projects have mutually compatible versions.

I typically declare `spring-boot-starter-parent` as **the parent POM of my parent POM**. This way, you get the best of both options.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to import the spring-boot-starter-parent pom. So you can use your own pom as parent and you can use the dependency management from the spring boot pom.

```
...
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

...

Comment: I changed my pom exactly the way pDer666 suggested, but now I get this error when running mvn install in the eclipse:


**'dependencies.dependency.scope' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'import'. @ line 26, column 17**

It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please update your question with a snippet of your pom file.

Comment: I added the pom to my question.

Comment: @fancytown Maven 2 had import scope.